# Comparing float and double in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I wrote the following code to compare between a float variable and a double variable in C.

```
int main()
{
    float f = 1.1;
    double d = 1.1;

    if(f==d)
        printf("EQUAL");

    if(f < d)
        printf("LESS");

    if(f > d)
        printf("GREATER");

    return 0;
}
```

I am using an online C compiler [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) to compile my code.

I know that EQUAL will never be printed for recurring decimals. However what I expect should be printed is LESS since double should have a higher precision and therefore should be closer to the actual value of 1.1 than float is. As far as I know, in C when you compare float and double, the mantissa of the float is zero-extended to double, and that zero-extended value should always be smaller.

Instead in all situations GREATER is being printed. Am I missing something here?

Comment: maybe it can be: float -> 1.09999999999 and double ->1.1 ... float does not round always to higher value, but the the closes representable

Comment: If the rounded value already is higher you can add as many zeroes as you like. It won't get smaller.

Comment: π to five decimal digits is 3.1416. π to ten decimal digits is 3.141592654. So five-digit π is greater than ten-digit π. When a decimal numeral in source code is converted to `float` or `double`, it is **rounded** to the nearest representable value, not truncated. (At least usually; there can be exceptions depending on language standards, quality of implementation, and such.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah that's where I made the mistake, I thought float values were truncated instead of rounded. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: regarding: `float f = 1.1;`  this is trying to squeeze a `double` literal into a `float` variable.  Much better to use: `float f = 1.1f;`  Note the trailing `f` that makes the literal into a `float` value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exact value of the closest float to 1.1 is 1.10000002384185791015625. The binary equivalent is 1.00011001100110011001101

The exact value of the closest double to 1.1 is 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625. The binary equivalent is 1.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010.

Lining up the two binary numbers next to each other:

```
1.00011001100110011001101
1.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

The first few truncated bits for rounding to float are 11001100, which is greater than half, so the conversion to float rounded up, making its least significant bits 11001101. That rounding resulted in the most significant difference being a 1 in the float in a bit position that is 0 in the double. The float is greater than the double, regardless of values of bits of lower significance being zero in the float extended to double, but non-zero in the double.

Answer (score 6):

If you'll add the following 2 lines after declaring the 2 variables:

```
printf("%.9g\n", f);
printf("%.17g\n", d);
```

you will get the following output:

```
1.10000002                                                                                                                  
1.1000000000000001
```

so it easy to see that due to *precision* the `float` is greater then the `double` thus the printing of `GREATER` is fine.

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct here. But I thought that the mantissa of the float was always zero-extended to double when comparing with a double? Is that not how it works?

Comment: @RijulGanguly Well, if you take 1.10000002 and zero-extend it, you get 1.1000000200000000, which is still greater than 1.1000000000000001, right? (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @SteveSummit exactly, this is pretty straight forward in that sense

Comment: "due to precision the float is greater then the double" mis-leads a tad.  Due to different precision, the values differ.  In this case, the `float` was greater.  About half of all non-exact _decimals_, the `double` will be greater.