# unexpected output while using float variable in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

//here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int i,ct=0;//ct is to count how many given inputs of W & H fulfill the if and else if conditional statements given below.
    float W,H,ratio;//W and H are width and rectangle of rectangle respectively.ratio is ratio b/w W&H.  
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f%f",&W,&H);
        ratio=W/H;
        printf("%f\n",ratio);
        if(ratio==1.7)//this statement is not getting executed for some reason
        {
            printf("true\n");
            ct++;
        }
        else if(ratio>1.6)
        {
            if(ratio<1.7)
            ct++;
        }   
    }
    printf("%d",ct);
}
```

note: when I give input as following

```
1 
10 1
```

supposed output is

```
ct=1
```

my output is

```
ct=0
```

//ratio is 1.7 but if statement above is not getting executed that's why ct is not getting updated
I want to know what is the problem with my above if statement.

Comment: I think `10.0f / 1.0 == 10.0f`. Why do you think `ratio` should be 1.7?

Comment: Also `ratio==1.7` won't work as expected. For more information, please read [floating point - Comparing float and double in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115928/comparing-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: Also your posted code doesn't have any statements to print `ct=`.

Comment: `ratio=W/H;` calculates a `float`. `1.7` is a `double` constant. They will not have the same value because `float` and `double` have different precisions, and a `double` value will be able to get closer to 1.7 than a `float` value can. In this particular case, you can avoid that by using the `float` constant `1.7f`. However, working with floating-point arithmetic requires understanding it, so you should expect other issues to arise.

Comment: If W and H are integers, then the correct way to solve the problem is by cross multiplying. `W/H == 1.7` if and only if `10*W == 17*H`.

Comment: @MikeCAT for inputs W=170 & H=100 ratio is = 1.7.Also yes I have not written "ct=",I only have printed the ct value which is supposed to be 1 for the input I mentioned but it prints 0.

Answer (score 0):

1.7 might b1 1.700000001

better use if (abs(ratio - 1.7) < 0.001)

Comment: You should use `fabs()` (from `math.h`) instead of `abs()` (from `stdlib.h`, only for integers).