# Reading float numbers using getchar() and printing the float number and it's double

Tags: arrays, c, floating-point, multiplication, getchar

I'm having trouble in converting numbers to float using **getchar()** method to solve my problem. For my problem I need to store characters in an array of `fixed size = 50`. Also, storing in an array only happens when there is a space `' '` or a newline `\n` read using getchar(). This happens until **EOF** is read. At last, the float number and it's double (with a tab space) is returned and printed using `printf`.

As per instructions, only getchar() is allowed. Functions like `scanf()`, `fgets()`, `atoi()`, `atol()`, `atof()`, `strtol()`, `strtoul()` or an extra array can not be used.

Here is what I've come up with till now. ( see sample input and output at bottom )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 50    // assume no more than 50 literals in input
int main(){
 
  float c;
  float u;
  float value = 0.0;
  float resu[SIZE];
  int index = 0;
  int i;
  char sub = '0';

  value = 0;
  c = getchar();
  while ( c != EOF){ 
    if(c == '.'){
      u = 0.1;
    }

    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n'){ 
      if(u == 0.1){
        value = value * 0.1;
    } 
      resu[index] = value;
      index++;
      value = 0;
    }

    if( c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
        value = value * 10 + (c-sub);
    }
    c = getchar(); // read next
  }
 
  //printing the result
  for(i=0; i < index; i++)
    printf("%.4lf \t %.4lf\n", resu[i],resu[i] *2.0);
 
  return 0;
}
```

**(Note- There is a tab between the original number and it's double)**

```
Sample Input: 
2.3 4.56
43.3 43 5.3
.3 1.2

Sample Output: 
2.3000    4.6000
45.6000    91.2000 //ERROR
43.3000    86.6000
4.3000    8.6000   //ERROR
5.3000    10.6000
0.3000    0.6000
1.2000    2.4000
```

Comment: `if(u == 0.1)` won't work well. `if(u == 0.1f)` will be better.

Comment: For more information, [floating point - Comparing float and double in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115928/comparing-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: `value = value + (c-sub) * 0.1;` I don't think you want to use `c` in the calculation when it is `' '` or `\n`.

Comment: Unless this is for an exercise, you should use scanf instead. Floats can be pretty tricky to parse.

Comment: 'u' is not initialised until the user enters a '.' character, but the value can already be used in a comparison.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I think you're right. I have made the changes to my code accordingly.

Comment: @Devolus, yes this is in fact an exercise. I have previously done this with scanf which was comparatively easy. Yes 'u' is not initialized until then, as to which input like '43' displays '4.3' which is an obvious error. I just can't recall what to do

Comment: @Devolus Unless this is for an exercise where the instructor has dictated that `scanf` must be used, it would be better to use `fgets` and `atof` or `strtod` instead. `scanf` can be pretty tricky -- unnecessarily and unforgivably tricky -- to use, too.

Comment: @SteveSummit, scanf was an example. :) I never used it, as I prefer the other functions as well. :)

Comment: The instructor does not want any functions to be used except getchar(). I'll update this information in my question. Thanks for reminding me @SteveSummit

Comment: Right now it looks like you handle at most one digit past the decimal point.  I assume you want to handle multiple. I would say you don't want to immediately do anything with `value` when you see a `.`.  I would say you just want to set a flag to remember that you have seen the decimal point.  If you haven't seen the decimal point, then for each digit character `c` that you see, you do `value = value * 10 + (c-sub)`, as you have now.  But if you have seen the decimal point, you'll want to do something else.  You might want `u` to go 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, etc.

Comment: @Nzed, don't know your instructions, but there are a lot of error conditions to consider. i.E. what happens if the user enters two '.', what about 'E' notation, etc. What you could do IMO is to read the first part as an integer and the second part as an integer and construct the float from that, which is probably easer. you still have to account for leading zeroes as in '12.00034' etc.

Comment: If you can only use getchar, I would write a function that converts a string to an integer (which is simple). Then I read the first part until a non-digit character occurss ('.', 'E', ' ', '\n') etc. after that, you have to count how many zeroes occure and the rest of the string can be just an integer value, which you use to construct the final float. Just read all characters into an array and parse that array. Makes it IMO easier to handle.

Comment: @Devolus, as per instructions ( also mentioned in the question now : updated ) - use of an extra array is not permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you don't do is initialize `u` or reset `u` for each word.

```
float u = 0;
....
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') { 
        if (u == 0.1){
            value = value * 0.1;
        } 
        resu[index] = value;
        index++;
        value = 0;
        u = 0;       // Reset it for next number
    }
```

Also, you hard-code `u = 0.1`, but that only works when there is only 1 decimal place. That may be ok for this assignment, but a better option would be to count the digits after the decimal.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
int digits_after_decimal = 0;
bool have_decimal_point = false;
int value = 0;
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    // Decimal point found?
    if ('.' == c) {
        have_decimal_point = true;
    }
    else if (isdigit(c)) {
        // Add this digit to integer value
        // Parentheses not required but added for clarity
        value = (value * 10) + (c - '0');
        // If decimal point already found, increment count
        if (have_decimal_point) digits_after_decimal += 1;
    }
    // Complete word. Save and reset
    // TODO: Multiple spaces between words?
    else if (' ' == c || '\n' == c) {
        // Divide by the correct power of 10 based on
        // the number of digits after the decimal point
        resu[index++] = value / pow(10, digits_after_decimal);
        if (index == SIZE) break;  // Avoid overflow
        // Reset for next number
        digits_after_decimal = 0;
        have_decimal_point = false;
        value = 0;
    }
    // TODO: Negative numbers?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For this exercise I have to neglect the negative numbers. The code works now.